# Error while restoring database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This error occurs while I restore database from .bak file

> *A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log
>   for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software
>   bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider
>   running DBCC CHECKDB. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3624)*

After this the Database goes offline and it property sets to Single User.

Comment: contact product support http://support.microsoft.com/

Comment: What does the SQL Server Log report?

Comment: What is `SELECT @@VERSION`? Have you run `DBCC CHECKDB` like the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1):

If `SELECT @@VERSION < 10.50.1746.0` then it is possible that the issue you are coming across has been fixed in a specific cumulative update, and can be averted by updating your instance.

The particular issue is described here:

[KB #980832 : FIX: "A system assertion check has failed" error message...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980832)

The cumulative update is here:

[Cumulative Update #4 for SQL Server 2008 R2 **RTM**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2345451)

But I recommend applying the most recent service pack and cumulative update available (since they come with a slew of other fixes as well):

[SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437)

[Cumulative Update #4 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777358)